# Rolling average of pandas timeseries with fixed duration window

Tags: pandas, time-series

In the docs it says

```
df.rolling('2s').sum()
```

is an option. However

```
ts = ts.rolling('900s').mean()
```

returns the error `ValueError: window must be an integer`

What's up with that? Can't share the whole timeseries, but this is a snippet:

```
2019-09-20 00:30:51.234260+00:00    4.63
2019-09-20 00:50:51.292892+00:00    4.40
2019-09-20 01:30:51.273058+00:00    4.54
2019-09-20 01:50:51.270876+00:00    4.44
2019-09-20 02:30:51.267385+00:00    4.55
                                    ... 
2019-10-30 22:57:35.003066+00:00    1.71
2019-10-30 23:12:34.965801+00:00    1.61
2019-10-30 23:27:34.976495+00:00    1.56
2019-10-30 23:42:34.984976+00:00    1.26
2019-10-30 23:57:34.965543+00:00    1.05
```

Comment: Convert your index to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: and also make sure that `datetime` is in the index.